# Moving repository from GitLab and Bitbucket, how to test this process that its done properly? (includes history, tags, commits, etc.)

Tags: git, testing, gitlab, bitbucket

Our Org is moving projects from GitLab to Bitbucket, hence our the process is complete. We need to test that nothing missing once the copy is done in Bitbucket (it should be as is as in GitLab).

Comment: Do you mean GitHub / GitLab or something similar instead of Git? Git is the version control tool, and repositories using git for tracking can be hosted by BitBucket, so it is not clear what moving from git to BitBucket means.

Comment: It is from Gitlab the transistion is being done. Ultimately , we will be using Bitbucket for all future use.